# Vue.js: Uncaught promises in vuex actions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex, nuxt.js

I understand vuex actions return promises, but I haven't found the **ideal pattern to handle errors** in vuex. My current approach is to use an error interceptor on my axios plugin, then committing the error to my vuex store.

*in* ***plugins/axios.js***:

```
export default function({ $axios, store }) {
    $axios.onError(error => {
        store.dispatch('setError', error.response.data.code);
    });
}
```

*in* ***store/index.js***:

```
export const state = () => ({
    error: null,
});

export const mutations = {
    SET_ERROR(state, payload) {
        state.error = payload;
    },
}

export const actions = {
    setError({ commit }, payload) {
        commit('SET_ERROR', payload);
    },
};
```

I would then use an **error component** watching the error state and show if there is an error. Thus there is really **no need to catch any errors** in either my action or in the component that dispatched the action. However I can't help to worry if it's **bad design leaving exceptions uncaught**? What issues could I encounter if I handle errors by this design? Suggestions on any better ways to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that you should make the API call in the vuex action and if it fails, reject the promise with the error from the API call. I would avoid listing to all Axios errors and instead handle the error when it is returned in the promise, in my opinion, it would be easier to maintain and debug this way
[image: vuex usage]

For example:

```
getCartItems: function ({commit}, url) {
    return axios.get(url).then(response => {
      commit('setCartItems', response.data)
      return response
    }).catch(error => {
      throw error
    })
 },
```

Comment: Why wrap in a new promise if `axios.get` already returns a promise? Simply return that promise.

Comment: @AdamReis That is absolutely a valid comment, I have now changed the example code, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Improved above example to avoid redundant promise wrapping and use async/await for simplified code:

```
export const getCartItems = async ({commit}, url) => {
  const response = await axios.get(url);
  commit('setCartItems', response.data)
  return response;
};
```