# Return axios Promise through Vuex

Tags: promise, axios, vuex

all!

I need to get axios Promise reject in my vue component using vuex.

I have serviceApi.js file:

```
export default {
  postAddService(service) {
    return axios.post('api/services', service);
  }
}
```

my action in vuex:

```
actions: {
    addService(state, service) {
        state.commit('setServiceLoadStatus', 1);

        ServicesAPI.postAddService(service)
            .then( ({data}) => {
                state.commit('setServiceLoadStatus', 2);
            })
            .catch(({response}) => {
                state.commit('setServiceLoadStatus', 2);
                console.log(response.data.message);
                return Promise.reject(response); // <= can't catch this one
            });
    }
}
```

and in my vue component:

```
methods: {
        addService() {
            this.$store.dispatch('addService', this.service)
                .then(() => {
                    this.forceLeave = true;
                    this.$router.push({name: 'services'});
                    this.$store.dispatch('snackbar/fire', {
                        text: 'New Service has been added',
                        color: 'success'
                    }).then()
                })
                .catch((err) => { // <== This never hapens 
                    this.$store.dispatch('snackbar/fire', {
                        text: err.response.data.message || err.response.data.error,
                        color: 'error'
                    }).then();
                });
}
```

When i use axios directly in my component all work well. I get both success and error messages.
But when i work using vuex i can't get error message in component, hoever in vuex action console.log prints what i need.
I'm always getting only successfull messages, even when bad things hapen on beckend.
How can i handle this situation using vuex ?

Comment: Your `actions.addService` doesn't  `return` anything. It should return the promise created by the `.then().catch()` chain.

Comment: Thank you, it works now.

Comment: An example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51260160/11421

Answer (score 0):

Wellcome to stackoverflow. One should not want to expect anything back from an action. After calling an action. Any response should be set/saved in the state via mutations. So rather have an `error` property on your state. Something like this should work

```
actions: {
    async addService(state, service) {
        try {
            state.commit('setServiceLoadStatus', 1);
            const result = await ServicesAPI.postAddService(service);
            state.commit('setServiceLoadStatus', 2);
        } catch (error) {
            state.commit("error", "Could not add service");
            state.commit('setServiceLoadStatus', 2);
            console.log(response.data.message);
        }
    }
}
```

And in your component you can just have an alert that listens on your `state.error`

Edit: Only time you are going expect something back from an action is if you want to call other actions synchronously using async /await. In that case the result would be a Promise.

Comment: Uhm the vuex docs clearly disagree https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#composing-actions

Comment: Please point out where it disagrees. Only time you are going expect something back from an action is if you want to call other actions synchronously using async /await. After that you would still mutate the result.

Comment: Well you specifically said "One should not want to expect anything back from an action." which the docs say you can do by using promises. Working like this you don't necessarily need a "pending" state - you can just wait for the promise to resolve. Don't think either way is necessarily wrong...